# Unable to pass array of fields data through serialize php

Tags: php, jquery

I have this form fields are dynamically generated

```
<form id="passengers_details">
        <div class="row clearfix passengerRow">
               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="first name" name="firstname[]">
                                        </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname[]">
                  </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number Optional" name="phone[]">
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
             <input type="email" placeholder="mail Id Optional" name="email[]">
             </div>
                                           
           </div>
      <a class="booked addPassengers">Add </a>
   </form>
```

> Script :

```
$(document).on('click', '.addPassengers', function(){
        console.log('add passengers ');


        var clone = $(".passengerRow").eq(0).clone(); 
        $("#passengers_details").append(clone); 

      });
```

i'm trying to pass form data with other fields through ajax

```
 jQuery.ajax({    
            url: "booking.php",
            data:'first_name='+$("#first_name").val()+
            '&serializePassengerData='+$("#passengers_details").serialize()+
            '&pkid='+$("#pkid").val(),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success:function(data){
```

but getting only first field value i.e. first name in php

```
print_r($_POST['serializePassengerData']); die();
```

if i console `$("#passengers_details").serialize()` all data is available.

Comment: Use "print_r($_POST);" in your PHP target file, and you will be notice what the problem is.

Comment: @user3653474 Any feedback on this one?

Answer (score 0):

`serialize()` is going to give you a complete query string, not a value you can simply add to a key inside a query string.

Use something like:

```
jQuery.ajax({    
    url: "booking.php",
    data: $("#passengers_details").serialize() +
    '&pkid='+$("#pkid").val(),
    type: "POST"
});
```

which on the server side will result in:

```
array(5) {
  ["firstname"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "First 1"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "First 2"
  }
  ["lastname"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Last 1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Last 2"
  }
  ["phone"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Phone 1"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Phone 2"
  }
  ["email"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Mail 1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Mail 2"
  }
  ["pkid"]=>
  string(9) "undefined"
}
```